# Node js es6 import and export

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

Doesn't the latest LTS version of Node.js require babel setup anymore to use ES6 syntax like import export default etc??. Should I update my node version?

Comment: i dont use the very latest version but i can either use `import` or `require()` in my node.js and i didnt setup anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes read their documentation for latest release of node

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html

and look at the screen shot

[image]